# cordova app is not running in Nexus, Motorol (google based android devices)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am developing one simple app in cordova 3.6.3 version and running it on Nexus 4(android Lolipop version is updated in the device), sometimes while running app will not load after splash screen, it shows dark screen

Below is the Logcat

03-12 17:23:33.757: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25260): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-12 17:23:53.545: I/CordovaLog(25651): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
03-12 17:23:53.546: D/CordovaActivity(25651): CordovaActivity.init()
03-12 17:23:53.640: I/WebViewFactory(25651): Loading com.google.android.webview version 37 (1602158-arm) (code 111201)
03-12 17:23:53.650: I/LibraryLoader(25651): Loading: webviewchromium
03-12 17:23:53.654: I/LibraryLoader(25651): Time to load native libraries: 5 ms (timestamps 1866-1871)
03-12 17:23:53.654: I/LibraryLoader(25651): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
03-12 17:23:53.674: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(25651): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {1abbb4e6}
03-12 17:23:53.676: I/LibraryLoader(25651): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
03-12 17:23:53.676: I/chromium(25651): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
03-12 17:23:53.687: I/BrowserStartupController(25651): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
03-12 17:23:53.688: W/art(25651): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
03-12 17:23:53.702: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
03-12 17:23:53.703: I/chromium(25651): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=32 off=46780 len=2953
03-12 17:23:53.704: I/chromium(25651): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:33 off:229484 len:643667
03-12 17:23:53.708: W/AudioManagerAndroid(25651): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
03-12 17:23:53.726: I/Adreno-EGL(25651): : QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
03-12 17:23:53.813: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
03-12 17:23:53.824: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
03-12 17:23:53.845: W/art(25651): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
03-12 17:23:53.858: W/AwContents(25651): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
03-12 17:23:53.880: D/CordovaWebView(25651): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: LGE
03-12 17:23:53.887: W/art(25651): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
03-12 17:23:53.887: W/art(25651): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
03-12 17:23:53.888: D/CordovaActivity(25651): CordovaActivity.createViews()
03-12 17:23:53.947: D/OpenGLRenderer(25651): Render dirty regions requested: true
03-12 17:23:53.953: D/Atlas(25651): Validating map...
03-12 17:23:53.959: D/CordovaWebView(25651): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
03-12 17:23:53.959: D/PluginManager(25651): init()
03-12 17:23:53.960: D/CordovaWebView(25651): >>> loadUrlNow()
03-12 17:23:53.973: D/CordovaActivity(25651): Resuming the App
03-12 17:23:53.996: I/OpenGLRenderer(25651): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-12 17:23:54.004: D/OpenGLRenderer(25651): Enabling debug mode 0
03-12 17:23:54.044: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(25651): Ignore this event
03-12 17:23:54.077: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(25651): Ignore this event
03-12 17:23:54.124: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(25651): Ignore this event
03-12 17:23:54.128: D/CordovaWebViewClient(25651): onPageStarted(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
03-12 17:23:54.129: D/CordovaActivity(25651): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
03-12 17:23:54.157: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(25651): Ignore this event
03-12 17:23:54.199: D/CordovaLog(25651): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 6 : The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.
03-12 17:23:54.199: I/chromium(25651): [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (6)
03-12 17:23:54.239: I/chromium(25651): [INFO:SkUtilsArm.cpp(179)] Device supports ARM NEON instructions!
03-12 17:23:54.958: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:ipc_channel_posix.cc(887)] Message needs unreceived descriptors channel:0xb907b878 message-type:1835287 header()->num_fds:1
03-12 17:23:54.961: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:54.962: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:raw_channel_posix.cc(214)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
03-12 17:23:55.055: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.055: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.055: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.055: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:23:55.056: W/chromium(25651): [WARNING:file_descriptor_set_posix.cc(22)] FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors
03-12 17:24:03.963: E/CordovaWebView(25651): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
id="com.m2f.hiddenobjects"
version="0.0.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" >

<preference
    name="loglevel"
    value="DEBUG" />

<name>
    M2F CI
</name>

<description>
    A Hidden Objects Game application that responds to the deviceready           event.
</description>

<author
    email="dev@cordova.apache.org"
    href="http://cordova.io" >
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>

<access
    origin="*"
    subdomains="true" />

<content src="index.html" />

<preference
    name="phonegap-version"
    value="3.6.3" />
<preference
    name="orientation"
    value="landscape" />

<access origin="*" />

<preference
    name="loadUrlTimeoutValue"
    value="10000" />
<preference  
    name="loglevel"
    value="DEBUG" />
<preference
    name="disallowOverscroll"
    value="true" />
<preference
    name="EnableViewportScale"
    value="true" />
<preference
    name="android-minSdkVersion"
    value="8" />
<preference
    name="orientation"
    value="landscape" />
<preference
    name="fullscreen"
    value="true" />
<preference
    name="SplashScreen"
    value="screen" />
<preference
    name="SplashScreenDelay"
    value="3000" />
```

Please anybody help me brothers..
I am facing this problem in this device only..
Any help much appreciated..

Comment: what is your target version?   i need your apk file android version

Comment: in the android menifest file <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Sdk and test the emulator after . use it. may helpful for you

it should include androidmanifest.xml file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

include your html page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , the problem is Chromium compatibility and web view. 
Try to use ionic with the crosswalk browser for a simple test in you nexus 4 lollipop.

Comment: I didnt get you sir.. now this problem is coming with all the devices NOT only nexus 4 lollipop.. This problem is coming randomly

Comment: Do you have started one app Cordova ? Example : device is ready ?

Comment: Ya from device ready event only im running other methods.. Its occurring only google based deives like nexus, motorola

Comment: i need another details of your situation, code source.

Comment: You would like to make Cordova game ?

Comment: Yes brother im developing cordova game.. what might be the problem?

Comment: Do You have used a lib (pixi.js,...) ?

Comment: Do you have try to turn fullscreen on ?

Comment: I finished my work, and I make you a clear and precise answer.